# why do I get example.com as redirect_uri when authenticating with facebook?

Tags: django, authentication, facebook

I have set up facebook authentication for my site.

When I click on "sign-in with facebook" it throws me to the following url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fla_facebook%2Fcallback&display=page&client_id=126197457491070
```

The redirect_url is "example.com", which is obviously not correct or allowed.

However, nowhere in my code or in the authentication package I'm using is example.com set, so this must be generated by facebook? Where can I change it? Why is it not the same as the domain and website I've set in the facebook app settings?

I get the following error because of that redirect_url:

```
{ 
   "error": { 
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not permitted by 
      the application configuration.", 
      "type": "OAuthException" 
  } 
}
```

I'm using Django with Heroku and django-la-facebook (https:// 
github.com/cartwheelweb/django-la-facebook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the code](https://github.com/cartwheelweb/django-la-facebook/blob/master/la_facebook/access.py) of the django app you are using for authenticating through facebook, you'll see something like this:

```
def callback_url(self):
        """
current site id
grab base site url
grab callback url
return base and callback url
"""

        current_site = Site.objects.get(pk=settings.SITE_ID)
        # @@@ http fix
        base_url = "http://%s" % current_site.domain
        callback_url = reverse("la_facebook_callback")
        return "%s%s" % (base_url, callback_url)
```

as burhan pointed, the default contrib.sites domain is being used as the base for the redirect uri, so you should fix it to be your actual domain.

Answer (score 2):

The default site from `django.contrib.sites` framework is example.com. You can change it from the default admin or via the django shell.

See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) for the sites framework for more information.